# JOIN multiple rows to multiple columns in single row Netezza/Postgres

Tags: sql, join, netezza

I have a table A that looks like this

```
Date         Name      Value
----------------------------
2015-01-01   A         12
2015-01-01   B         13
2015-01-01   C         10
2015-01-01   D          9
2015-01-01   E         15
2015-01-01   F         11
2015-01-02   A          1
2015-01-02   B          2
2015-01-02   C          3
2015-01-02   D          4
2015-01-02   E          5
2015-01-02   F          6
2015-01-03   A          7
2015-01-03   B          8
2015-01-03   C          9
2015-01-03   D         10
2015-01-03   E         15
2015-01-03   F         16
....
```

Which contains a value for each name for each day. I need a second table which looks like this

```
Date         Name    ValueDate    ValueDate+1     ValueDate+2
--------------------------------------------------------------
2015-01-01   A         12            1                7
2015-01-01   B         13            2                8
2015-01-01   C         10            3                9
2015-01-01   D          9            4               10
2015-01-01   E         15            5               15
2015-01-01   F         11            6               16
2015-01-02   A          1            7              ...
2015-01-02   B          2            8              ...
2015-01-02   C          3            9              ...
2015-01-02   D          4           10              ...
2015-01-02   E          5           15              ...
2015-01-02   F          6           16              ...
```

I tried creating an intermediate table which has all the dates correctly entered

```
Date         Name    ValueDate      ValueDate+1     ValueDate+2
----------------------------------------------------------------
2015-01-01   A         2015-01-01    2015-01-02      2015-01-03
2015-01-01   B         2015-01-01    2015-01-02      2015-01-03
2015-01-01   C         2015-01-01    2015-01-02      2015-01-03
2015-01-01   D         2015-01-01    2015-01-02      2015-01-03
2015-01-01   E         2015-01-01    2015-01-02      2015-01-03
2015-01-01   F         2015-01-01    2015-01-02      2015-01-03
...
```

My idea then was to use some kind of JOIN on table a to map the the corresponded Values to the dates and use s.th like

```
CASE WHEN Date = ValueDate THEN Value ELSE NULL END AS ValueDate+1
```

I am struggling to figure out how this can be done in SQL. I essentially need all the Values over a window for an initial date sequence. To give some background I want to see for a regular time interval how the value behaves in the following x days. The Datatypes are Date for all the Date columns, Varchar for the Name and numerics for the Values. The ValueDate+1 and +2 means +1/2 days. Also it cannot be ruled out that the counts of names stays constant over time.

thanks

Comment: To me this is two left joins and a pivot.  assuming your [version of netezza](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21669899) supports `pivoting`... you may have to use dynamic sql to generate the dates names as a column header though especially if the number of column is variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way of getting the desired results, by writing a row_number() sub select limit to the desired window size. Which gives each entry per date s.th like this

```
Date         Name      Value    Row_Num
---------------------------------------
2015-01-01    A         12        0
2015-01-01    A         12        1
2015-01-01    A         12        2
2015-01-01    A         12        3
```

In the next step one can use

```
(Date + Row_Num*INTERVAL'1 DAY')::DATE
```

which then can be joined on the initial table and pivoted. This will allow for any arbitrary combination of Names per date.

Answer (score 1):

You just want `lead()`:

```
select a.*,
       lead(value) over (partition by name order by date) as value_1,
       lead(value, 2) over (partition by name order by date) as value_2
from a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this doesn't work if the name counts per date change over time, which I cannot rule out

Comment: @Markus.london . . . I don't understand your comment.  This should be fetching the value from the "next" row of the table for each name, where "next" is the next in order by date.  That seems to be what you are asking for.

Comment: I might have cases where e.g Name A is missing for some days, would that work as well ?

Comment: @Markus.london . . . It gives the value from the next date in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear about your problem statement --

First, you don't say if the "Date" in your data is a Date type, or just a string that looks like a date.

Is "Value" the primary key for each line of data?  Or is it an actual value used in the computation of "ValueDate+1"?  If so, how?

Is "ValueDate" simply the value of "Date", and "ValueDate+1" the day after the "Date"?  Or is it the month after?

Is ValueDate supposed to be the value of the "Date" plus "Value" days?

Could you restate the problem, and include types of your data?

Can you state the problem with equations, or formulas, along with the type of output values you need to show?

If you can, I can show you how to format it in SQL.

-- Ada

Comment: I have added the datatypes, the ValueDate+1 is simple the Value at date+1 day. There are no formulas it is about rearranging the existing values in a way that you can see how each 'Name' changes in the following days. The values all come from table a